# How to show the after-processed video data on the view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I am doing a dynamic tone project now using the AVFoundation. I use AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate to get the video data from the camera and try to process it with the method setImageWithTexture:, which will return a UIImage with the tone style. But when I try to show it on a UIImageView with the code below, its memory will grow fast and the program will be killed because of the high memory using. How can I fix the issue?

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:    (CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{
     // Create a UIImage from the sample buffer data
     UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
     NSLog(@"get pic");
     UIImage * imageOut = [[ToneTool sharedManager] setImageWithTexture:image];
     self.imgView.image = imageOut;
}
```

Comment: Try comment out `UIImage * imageOut = [[ToneTool sharedManager] setImageWithTexture:image];` and add `self.imgView.image = image`. Then you can see whether the UIImageView/UIImage or the set-tone action leads the memory rises.

Comment: @jojoT How can u find me:)

Comment: Try it and it may help you with.